# Copying Single Cell to .txt file

Tags: excel, vba

I came across this code online which copies the whole worksheet.

I tried changing it to copy a single cell but I get the error:

> Compile Error - Expected Array

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim R As Long, C As Long, FF As Long
Dim TextLine As String, TextOut As String
Dim Data As Range
Data = Range("E4")

For R = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
    TextLine = ""
    For C = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
        TextLine = TextLine & vbTab & Cells(R, C)
    Next
    TextOut = TextOut & vbCrLf & Mid(TextLine, 2)
Next

TextOut = Mid(TextOut, 3)
FF = FreeFile
Open "C:\Users\Username\NewText.txt" For Output As #FF
Print #FF, TextOut
Close #FF

End Sub
```

I had to change the data type to range to fix another error but it's now thrown this.

As well how can I get it to copy a selected cell to the text file?

Comment: If you just want to copy a single cell you dont really need to keep the `For` loops at all. You can just say `TextOut = Range("E4")`

Comment: You are trying to deal with Range object as like with an Array object, that's why an error is thrown (UBound can't be applied to Range object). Replace all lines starting from `For R=1...` to last `Next` but keep the line `TextOut = TextOut & vbCrLf & Mid(TextLine, 2)` (if you need it), with `TextLine = TextLine & vbTab & Range("E4")` line and try again

Comment: Correct, remove the whole `For` ... `Next` loop and simply use `TextOut = Range("E4")` for a single cell's value. As for your bonus question, you can use `TextOut = AcitveCell.Value`.

Comment: @JustynaMK you may see that there are some manipulations with the text (adding a `vbTab` and then `vbCrLf` characters), so it can't be just `TextOut = Range("E4")`

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak fair point! But it should work nicely if you remove the whole `For`...`Next` loop - just like [that](https://i.imgur.com/zZpRK06.png) :)

Comment: Thank you very much guys, all sorted with your advice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   Dim ff As Long
   ff = FreeFile
   Open "C:\Users\Username\NewText.txt" For Output As #ff
   Print #ff, ActiveCell.Value
   Close #ff
```

(Replace `ActiveCell` by `Range("E4")` if you need the latter).